# MySql table merging with sum

Tags: mysql, merge, sum

My twp tables like this.

```
+----+--------+   +----------+-------+--------+
| id | fruit  |   | fruit_id | color | amount |
+----+--------+   +----------+-------+--------+
```

Result for:

```
SELECT
  fruit,amount
FROM
  table1,table2
WHERE fruit_id = id

+--------+--------+
| fruit  | amount |
+--------+--------+
| Apple  |      5 |
| Apple  |      5 |
| Cherry |      2 |
| Cherry |      2 |
+--------+--------+
```

But I want this result:

```
+--------+--------+
| fruit  | amount |
+--------+--------+
| Apple  |     10 |
| Cherry |      4 |
+--------+--------+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will use the aggregate function `sum()` and a `GROUP BY` to get the result:

```
SELECT t1.fruit, sum(t2.amount) Total
FROM table1 t1
inner join table2
  on t2.fruit_id = t1.id
group by t1.fruit
```

As a side note, you should use standard ANSI join syntax with an INNER JOIN.

Comment: This OK "SELECT fruit, sum(amount) Total FROM table1
inner join table2 on fruit_id = id group by fruit" Thenks...

Comment: @MahmutEsinti Yes that is correct, that should return the result.

Comment: @MahmutEsinti You will want to use a `LEFT JOIN` instead of an INNER JOIN

Comment: @bluefeet one *more question:* How can I do, also return items `where amount = 0` or fruit not in amount table